# Can we declare a newtype with a function?

Tags: haskell, newtype

```
newtype State s a = StateOf (s -> (s, a))
```

`(s -> (s, a))` is a function, isn't it?

`newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (s, a) }` such expression make sense since record syntax is allowed.

Comment: The answers to both the question in the title and the one in your body are "yes". Beyond that, I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Why wouldn't this be possible? Remember that, in Haskell, functions are also data.

Answer (score 2):

> `(s -> (s, a))` is a function, isn't it?

Not sure if that answers your question, but: technically speaking *no*, `(s -> (s, a))` is not a function, it's a *function type*. I.e., a type whose values are functions. Thus `State` is a new type whose values are internally given as functions (but from the outside, are just “values of some opaque, named type”).

Comment: It's only opaque if the constructor isn't exported, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Functions are values, too. As far as defining a type, record syntax simply provides a shortcut for

```
newtype State s a = StateOf (s -> (s, a))

runState :: State s a -> s -> (s, a)
runState (StateOf f) = f
```

(Record syntax also provides additional pattern-matching and value construction syntax.)